# Permission levels based on terms

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-server, security

I'm new to SharePoint (working with SP 2013 Enterprise on-premises) and have a question. Consider we have several privacy levels stored in a termset and a SharePoint list. Privacy term is a field of list item. Then I created User Groups according to privacy levels. After that I add a user in some group and want him to have appropriate access. So if some user is in Group "Level A" then he is able to see only "Level A" items. What are my options? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, bus this cannot be made OOB, without custom development. You will have several options:

- **Create a event receiver**, that manages permissions of the list item (or document in the library), when it is created or updated.
- **Create a workflow** (with Visual Studio or SharePoint designer) what manages permissions and it should start when item is created or updated.

**VERY IMPORTANT**, that unique permissions on every item in the library is not very recommended. My recommendation would be, to create a folder for each of your security level. Then you can define permissions on each folder.

In this scenario, you could set permissions on every folder and you event receiver or workflow, should not modify permissions, but only move the item (or document) to the specific folder.

If you do not like folders in the view, you could create a recursive view, that shows item or documents in plain view without folders.

Comment: Thank you! Created event receiver to sort items in three folders with appropriate permissions, works like a charm!